# How to setup a TCP client Connection to a Wireless to serial adapter and send data to it using java

Tags: java, networking, tcp, adapter

I'm a mature student studying mobile comms and electronic engineering which allows me to learn Java which I'm not as skilled as I would like but thats what this post is for.

My delima is that I want to write a Java program that connects to my wireless to serial adapter (Wiz6000) using a tcp connection but the problem is that I have the code which I think works in creating the connection but when I connect a USB to serial converter to the serial output of the adapter and set up a link with Hyper-Terminal there's no data received by the wifi to serial adapter.

I have included the code that I have so far below

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client1 {

    // Modify this value (xxx.xxx.x.xxx) to the IP address you want your client to connect to (the server’s IP address)
    static String hostString = "192.168.1.254"; 

    // Modify this value (xxxxx) to the port number that the server is accepting connections on
    static int portInt = 5000;  

    static Socket connectionSocket = null;
    static PrintWriter out = null;
    static BufferedReader in = null;
    static String fromUserString = null;
    static String fromServer = null;
    static BufferedReader stdIn = null;
    static String hostInetAddressString = null;  
    public int data;    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            connectionSocket = new Socket(hostString, portInt);
            hostString = connectionSocket.getInetAddress().toString();
            out = new PrintWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));

            // Get the Inet Address of the connectionSocket and store it in the hostInetAddress InetAddress variable and then cast the hostInetAddress to a String named hostInetAddressString
            hostInetAddressString = connectionSocket.getInetAddress().toString();
            System.out.println("Connected to server with Inet Address " +     hostInetAddressString + " on port: " + connectionSocket.getPort() + "\n");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // This is used to allow the client to receive input based on the program’s user pressing keys on their keyboard

        /* stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (true) {
        try {
        if (fromUserString != null) {
        int data=Integer.parseInt(fromUserString);
        out.println(fromUserString);
        fromUserString = null;
        }   
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        break;
        }
        }*/
        try
        {
            // Create a new instance of a OutputStreamWriter object
            // attached to a ByteArrayOutputStream.
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "ASCII");

            // Write to the output stream.
            String s = "Hello World";
            writer.write(s);
            writer.flush();

            // Display the contents of the ByteArrayOutputStream.
            System.out.println(out.toString());

            // Display the encoding being used.
            System.out.println("encoding: " + writer.getEncoding());

            // Close the OutputStreamWriter object.
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

I have spent the last week looking at different sites reading up on Java sockets client and server, serial comms and serializing but I just don't know which way to go with it.

The main objective of this is to create an application that connects to this wifi to serial adapter and takes information off a user and sends it over the wifi connection where at the other end the wifi to serial is connected to a PCB that controls a digital display.  The PCB is manufactured by an electronics company that I work part time for and is setup in a way that it can recive commands via serial connection.

So in short I want the app to connect to a digital display via wireless connection and send data out to be displayed.

Comment: See if you can obtain a simple command line program called netcat (available for most operating systems) and use it to test all parts of the system that aren't your java code.  If that works, then you know the problem is in your code - but if it doesn't work, then you know you have problems outside of your code in addition to any problems there might be within in your code.  You can also use netcat in listen (server) mode to test your java code against.

Comment: I have just downloaded netcat and will play around with it later.  Thanks for the comment.